# Which kinds of Wi-Fi networks cause Windows to automatically uncheck the "Automatically Connect" checkbox within the Network and Sharing Center?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

When connecting to certain Wi-Fi networks (mainly in public places or when performing the initial setup of a wireless-based device), I've noticed that the "Connect Automatically" checkbox is automatically unchecked. Which kinds of networks cause Windows to assume that you wouldn't want to automatically reconnect to these particular networks in the future?